# Validating fields as unique in cakephp 3.0

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How do you validate a field is unique in cakephp 3.0? There doesn't appear to be a validation function listed in the API.

Answer (score 20):

You want to use the rule `validateUnique`. For example, to check an email address is unique on an `UsersTable`:-

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->add(
        'email', 
        ['unique' => [
            'rule' => 'validateUnique', 
            'provider' => 'table', 
            'message' => 'Not unique']
        ]
    );

    return $validator;
}
```

Details can be found in [the API docs](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_validateUnique).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I was using buildRules(RulesChecker $rules) which was working fine but not giving proper error message

Comment: Found an issue not working during edit time. Can you plz help?

Answer (score 6):

you have to use the rules from cake's ORM on your table...

add this at the top of your UsersTable after your namespace

```
use Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique;
```

Then prepare your rule to apply to your field by placing it in a public function

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules){
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
        return $rules;
    }
```

Consult the cakephp documentation for more information about [RULES](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-a-rules-checker)

Comment: How to show custom message instead of, `Provided value is invalid` for unique fields?

Comment: I correct myself, isUnique has only 2 parameters, 
`public function isUnique(array $fields, $message = null){`
so your code will be like:
`$rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email'],'Your message here!'));`

Answer (score 3):

Validation providers can be objects, or class names. If a class name is used the methods must be static. To use a provider other than ‘default’, be sure to set the `provider` key in your rule:

```
// Use a rule from the table provider
$validator->add('title', 'unique', [
    'rule' => 'uniqueTitle',
    'provider' => 'table'
]);
```

For more details, look at the [Adding Validation Providers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html) section in the CakePHP3 reference book.

Comment: Good Reference [Click Here CakePHP _validateUnique](https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_validateUnique)

Answer (score 0):

Use application rules as described in [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-unique-field-rules).

Comment: The link provided by ADMad is the an excellent and possibly the best solution.

In your Table's _buildRules_ function, add a rule:

`$rules->add($rules->isUnique(['UNIQUE_COLUMN']));`

Answer (score 0):

> Kindly please check this for unique validation in cakephp 3.8
>   [go to site](http://viralcrews.co.in/2020/01/17/unique-field-validation-in-cake-php-3-8-model/)

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->requirePresence('login_id');
    return $validator;
}

public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['login_id'], 'User already exist.'));
    return $rules;  
}
```